# IndexError in loop function while passing arguments with np.vectorize

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I am passing numpy arrays to a function using *np.vectorize*, but the function is not recognizing indexes of the arrays... or something else is going on but I am getting the error *IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable* at this line in the code:

```
if (value[r-1] == 0) & (value[r] != 0):
```

The function loops through 300k values that's why I am using *vectorize* to maximize speed. The loop is unavoidable. The arguments passed to the function are coming from a dataframe.  The function returns three lists, two of which are used to replace the original columns in the Panda dataframe.

```
def CumRain(value, event, crain, length):
    for r in range(1, length):
        numeven = 1
        if (value[r-1] == 0) & (value[r] != 0):
            event[r] = numeven
            crain[r] = value[r]
        elif (value[r-1] != 0) & (value[r] != 0):
            event[r] = numeven
            crain[r] = value[r] + crain[r-1]
        elif (value[r-1] != 0) & (value[r] == 0):
            event[r] = 0
            numeven = numeven + 1
        else:
            numeven = numeven
    return [event, crain, numeven]

df_rain['Event_Group_allYears', 'CUM_Rain'] = np.vectorize(CumRain)       
      (df_rain['RD_VALUE'].to_numpy(), df_rain['Event_Group_allYears'].to_numpy(), 
      df_rain['CUM_Rain'].to_numpy(), len(df_rain['RD_VALUE']))
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.  I am very new to Python so errors could have been made anywhere... :-)

Comment: The boolean "and" operator in Python is the word `and`, not the `&` operator.

Comment: Your function is going to get called with each element, one at a time.  If you need to look ahead or look back, then you can't use `vectorize`.  You'll have to pass the columns directly.

Comment: I was going to post an answer by passing `df_rain['RD_VALUE'].to_numpy()[1:]` as a second column, but the fact that you have to retain state (`numeven`) from call to call makes that difficult.

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalar values to your function.  As the error says `scalar variable`.  You can't index `value`, `event` or `crain`.  And despite the name `np.vectorize` is not a performance tool (read its docs!).  It is slower than plain iteration.   `np.vectorize` does not 'reach into' your function and compile it.

Comment: I suspect your `CUM_Rain` could be written without the loop.  For example the first test could be `mask = (value[:-1]==0)&(value[1:]!=0)` and `event[1:][mask] = numeven`.

Comment: When you have problems with arguments from a function like `np.vectorize` , it's a good idea to add a few diagnostic prints to your function.  Display the `value` and its type.

Comment: @TimRoberts  thanks for your comments. I will look into it.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for your response. I will be testing the mask you proposed this evening. Need to get familiar with what it is doing.